# ReactJS - Using setState with firebase listen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Well I already knew that we should do something like this to keep the state up to date with firebase changes.

```
import FirebaseRef from '...'
   .
.
.
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
 state = {
      maxVotes: 0  
    }

componentDidMount() {
   const { boardId } = this.props
   FirebaseRef.child(`boards/${boardId}/maxVotes`).on('value', snapshot => {
      this.setState({maxVotes: snapshot.val()})
   })
}
```

But my habit of coding is to delegate API call in other file and import it to component. Can I do something like this?

```
import { setMaxVotes } from ...
.
.
.
 componentDidMount() {
   const { boardId } = this.props
   setMaxVotes(boardId)
}
```

And how does the setMaxVotes method looklike ? Should I complicate thing like this, or it's not best pratice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common to delegate API calls to different modules but setting the react component state in different module is not a best practice. So you can create different module for API calls but you should set the state in component itself. The code may look something like this

```
componentDidMount() {
   const { boardId } = this.props
   setMaxVotes(boardId, 'value', snapshot => {
      this.setState({maxVotes: snapshot.val()})
   })
}

setMaxVotes(boardId, eventType, cb) {
   FirebaseRef.child(`boards/${boardId}/maxVotes`).on(eventType, cb);
}
```